# Why is いる in いらせらる conjugated いら, in 未然形, instead of 入り?

Tags: conjugations, archaic-language

いらせらる consists of いる and せらる, the passive of suru I think, so why is it in 未然形? Usually, if a verb is and can be paired with する, it'd be in continuative form, so you'd say things like 入りもしない、 or 入りやしない. It makes no sense, unless it's actually いらせる/いらす + らる.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**いらせらる** = ***ir-ase-rar-u*** (→ modern [いらっしゃる](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%82%8B))

***ir-*** = **stem**

***-(s)ase-*** = Causative (Variant with initial *s* was used with most vowel-stem verbs, except verb *se-* (す, modern する).) (This suffix itself was weak-vowel-stem verb ([二段活用]{にだんかつよう}).) **(In the context of etymology of いらっしゃる, honorific/respectual function of this suffix should be assumed.)**

***-(r)are-*** = Spontaneous/Passive/Potential/**Honorific** (Variant with initial *r* was used with most vowel-stem verbs, except verb *se-* (す, modern する).) (This suffix itself was weak-vowel-stem verb ([二段活用]{にだんかつよう}).) **(In the context of etymology of いらっしゃる, honorific/respectual function of this suffix should be assumed.)**

***-u*** = **Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい}**

いらせらる must be from Middle Japanese, but Middle Japanese preserved behavior of attaching of *-u* resulting from rules of phonology of Old Japanese. <sub>(Frellesvig (2010, page 63): "The passive auxiliary variant *-rare-*, attaching to vowel base verbs, does not appear in the language until EMJ (see 8.4.1) and forms no part of OJ, although it is included in some grammars.")</sub>

In Old Japanese, in most cases, 2 consecutive vowels were not allowed. When inflection would cause appearance of consecutive vowels, either fusion of them, or elision of one of them must have occurred.

For weak-vowel-stem verbs ([二段活用]{にだんかつよう}), when attaching suffix beginning with vowel (e.g. *-u*), last vowel of stem is elided and first vowel of suffix is preserved. Examples:

*-(r)are-* + *-u* → *-(r)aru* (modern *-(r)areru*)

*ide-* + *-u* → *idu* (出{い}づ, modern 出{で}る)

*miti-* + *-u* → *mitu* (満{み}つ, modern 満{み}ちる)

For strong-vowel-stem verbs ([一段活用]{いちだんかつよう}), when attaching suffix beginning with vowel (e.g. *-u*), last vowel of stem is preserved and first vowel of suffix is elided. Examples:

*mi-* + *-u* → *mi* (見{み}, modern 見{み}る)

*ni-* + *-u* → *ni* (似{に}, modern 似{に}る)

---

At least synchronically, Attributive/[連体形]{れんたいけい} of all vowel-stem verbs was created by attaching *-ru* to Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい}:

*-(r)aru* + *-ru* → *-(r)aruru* (modern *-(r)areru*)

*idu* + *-ru* → *iduru* (出{い}づる, modern 出{で}る)

*mitu* + *-ru* → *mituru* (満{み}つる, modern 満{み}ちる)

*mi* + *-ru* → *miru* (見{み}る, modern 見{み}る)

*ni* + *-ru* → *niru* (似{に}る, modern 似{に}る)

Since Early Middle Japanese, Attributive/[連体形]{れんたいけい} of strong-vowel-stem verbs (一段活用) (e.g. *miru*, *niru*) was used as Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい}, and original forms (e.g. *mi*, *ni*) were no longer used.

Many centuries later, similar replacement of Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい} with Attributive/[連体形]{れんたいけい} occurred for almost all other verbs which formerly had distinction (weak-vowel-stem verbs, irregular verbs) and adjectives (modern *-i* adjectives) (suppletive copula *da* / *na* still has distinction between Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい} and Attributive/[連体形]{れんたいけい}, but these are forms which evolved in Late Middle Japanese or Early Modern Japanese; originally main extended copula was *ni ar-* / *nar-*: Conclusive/Terminal/[終止形]{しゅうしけい} *ni ar(i|u)* / *nar(i|u)*, Attributive/[連体形]{れんたいけい} *ni aru* / *naru*).

---

いらせらる does not include any form of verb する.

---

Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", page 369, 371):

> 12.7 Honorific language
>
> Through its history Japanese has had grammatical expression of what is very generally characterized as *honorific language* (*keigo* 敬語). It is common to distinguish two independent parameters: *exaltation* (12.7.1) and *politeness* (12.7.2).
>
> 12.7.1 Exaltation
>
> Exaltation characterizes the social relation between those spoken about, or between the speaker and those spoken about, and exaltation is sometimes referred to as *social deixis*. Two overall parameters are distinguished: (a) 'respect' (*sonkei* 尊敬), also referred to as 'esteemed subject', 'respect for subject', 'subject exaltation'; and (b) 'humility' (*kenjō* 謙譲), which in the Japanese descriptive tradition, which focuses on the subject, may be termed 'humble subject', but which in more recent scholarship in English is referred to as 'respect for object' (or indirect object), or 'object exaltation'; here we use the English equivalents of the Japanese terms, *respect* and *humility*, for these two categories.
>
> (...)
>
> 12.7.1.2 Predicate exaltation
>
> Overall, exaltation on predicates has been expressed in three main ways, namely by (a) auxiliaries, e.g. OJ *-(a)s-* RESP, *-(a)sime-* CAUS (enhancing a following respect expression); EMJ/LMJ *-rare-* PASS (used for respect), *-sase-* CAUS (enhancing a following respect expression), (b) auxiliary verbs, e.g. *-tamap-* RESP, *-mawir-* HUM, *-tatematur-* HUM, and (c) lexical suppletion, e.g. *imas-* 'be, come, go, RESP', *kakur-* 'die' ('hide oneself'), *tukapematur-* 'serve.HUM', *mawos-* 'say.HUM, speak.HUM', *mawir-* 'enter.HUM', and many, many others. As mentioned, the expression of humility has always been less developed than respect, and this is also reflected in the fact that humility has never been expressed by auxiliaries, only by auxiliary verbs and suppletive lexical verbs.
>
> The inventories of forms used in these functions have changed over time, as have rules for their combinations. However, with a few exceptions the basic system of respect and humility has not changed much between OJ and cNJ. In Old Japanese, as opposed to later stages, 'respect for subject' could be used by the speaker about himself, e.g. *wa ga tata-s-ere-ba* I GEN stand-RESP-STAT.PROV 'as I stand' (*KK* 2), spoken by the god *Yachihoko no kami no mikoto*. This is referred to as 'absolute [as opposed to relative] respect' and disappeared in the transition to EMJ. Exaltation is ubiquitous in the literary prose texts from EMJ and early LMJ. Not only were multiple, mutually reenforcing combinations of respect expressions used, such as *-sase-rare-tamap-* CAUS-PASS-RESP, expressing a high degree of respect, but humility and respect was often expressed on one verb, usually expressing the respect of the speaker (writer) towards the subject of the verb, but expressing the humility of the subject towards the (indirect) object, for example in the combination *-tatematuri-tamap-* HUM-RESP. The combination of respect and humility went out of use in late LMJ and is no longer part of the system. The varied and frequent use of exalting expressions is so prominent in the literary texts from EMJ and early LMJ, especially the *monogatari*, that it is a distinctive feature of the appearance and image of these texts. It is, however, not likely that exalting expressions were as widely used in common language as they were in the refined and elegant language of the court ladies and nobles. Through LMJ, the use of exalting expressions in the texts declined somewhat, probably reflecting more everyday and less elegant language use, rather than structural changes. In cNJ, exalting language has been regularized to mainly morphological expression, with a small number of auxiliaries and auxiliary verbs and far fewer suppletive verbs than in EMJ or LMJ. It should finally be mentioned that despite the prominence of the use of exalting expressions in metalinguistic consciousness and the importance assigned to it in normative discourse about Japanese, a number of Japanese dialects do not use exalting language.

Comment: Okay so I was right about the causative form but why would it mean いる 来る etc. When it's their causative passive form. And would this mean that  いらっしゃる could be, although not everyday, used with に to mean someone makes me do ()? How exactly does the に work then since it's causative passive?

Comment: @StarPeep None of these suffixes have more standard causative and passive functions here. They are used for honorific/respectual function. I added quotes from chapter about honorific language.

Comment: @Arfrever, I don't think that analysis ([VERB]_-e_ + conclusive _-u_ → _-u_) is accepted throughout.  I'm more familiar with an alternative hypothesis, that the 二段 verb paradigm evolved as a variant on 四段 roots. Some of these are still extant in modern Japanese, like つく・つける. In this view, forms like _idu_ would have been the original root verb, and we have things like _idasu_ that only work if we posit either 1) _idu_ had a 四段 pattern at some point, or 2) the causative was not _-su_ but _-asu_ with the medial _-a-_ disappearing in various conditions.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I do not know how 二段 verbs originally developed, but they may have developed in some way, and then suffix *-u* was added to them... Anyway I also recommend to read Frellesvig (2010, pages 106-109, 118-123), Vovin (2020, pages 535-537).

Comment: Frellesvig (2010, page 120) mentions: 「reinterpretation of the basic stems of all ancestors of QD verbs as having the basic stem shape CVC-, regardless of their etymological root shape (OJ *yak-* < pre-OJ \*yak-, *yos-* < \*yəsə-).」, 「OJ *yos-* 'draw close TR' is used as an example of a QD verb originating in an open (vowel final)
root; OJ *yosor-* 'approach' and *yose-* 'draw close TR' point to a common open root for all three, \*yəsə-.」

Comment: Given the prevalence of verb clusters that still have both 四段・二段, the clearly defective nature of the 二段 conjugation paradigm, and the difficulties presented by postulating any _-asu_ form for the causative, just from parsimony and simplicity, conclusive _idu_ as just _idu_ seems more elegant. If we posit consonant-final verb roots, then _idu_ would not be _ide-_ + _-u_ but rather _id-_ + _-u_, also more elegant.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi (I think that your comments are more about situation in Proto-Japonic or some stage of Japanese before Old Japanese.) Are/were there any 二段 verbs in Ryukyuan languages?

Comment: @Arfrever, my knowledge of the Ryukyuan branch is more limited, I'm afraid. From what I've learned so far, it seems that Okinawan verbs mostly derive from 連用形 + をる -- plus, Japanese /e/ and /i/ both reflect as /i/ in Okinawan. So we lose any distinction between 四段 and 二段 verbs. I'm not sure about other Ryukyuan languages, however.